# Gunicorn failing with symlinks in Kubernetes

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, gunicorn

I am running Gunicorn with a Flask app in a Kubernetes cluster and have some symlink for configuration files.

For example:
`/home/application/con.cfg` is linked to `/home/application/stage/my_config.cfg`

I am able to see symlinks in the Kubernetes pods.
But it fails when Gunicorn starting with an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/application/con.cfg
```

When I hard-code the path in python code, it works fine.

Comment: How are you mounting the actual config file into the pod?

Comment: It should work unless the file is not really there. Can you post your pod definition?

Comment: Thanks Rico and David,Actually it was my mistake at one place i left forward slash.This is working fine now.